# Analysis of 100 questions on Yahoo's Genealogy answers

Tags: discussion, scope

I promised to do an analysis of the topic areas for comparison purposes of the Genealogy questions at [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index;_ylt=AspzkKWcBwPGOoRp4w2BqzOSxQt.;_ylv=3?sid=396546034&link=list).

To find 100 questions that we would deem on-topic (drawing the lines generously) I had to trawl 145 questions, i.e. 31% of the questions there be off-topic here. (I did not attempt to eliminate questions that would have been closed for other purposes e.g. duplicates, as I was losing the will to live and needed to **find** 100 questions before I did).

Breakdown is as follows [our figures in brackets]:

- Application of technology 9% (of which 'What website should I use'  was 8%) [12%]
- Research process etc. 23% (of which 'What is this relationship called' was 10%) [28%]
- Locating records 19% [30%]
- Interpreting records 2% [13%]
- Researching specific ancestors 8% [14%]
- Other specialist topics 39% (of which 'What is the origin of this surname' was 19%. and questions about ethnicity were 13%) [3%]

A very different mix.... Discuss!

[Edited to correct percentages. I blame traumatic stress at the time]

Comment: After reviewing those questions, if you were a professional genealogist, how many of them would you feel are worthy of you answering? What would be the equivalent number for 100 posts here? I don't want you to go through them again, because you need to retain your will to live, but just give us an estimate based on the general impression you got.

Comment: @lkessler, there were maybe 3 or 4 very good questions, and maybe 10 that with work could have been OK questions (although almost all duplicates about starting out in FH or finding basic BMD records).

Comment: I want to publicly acknowledge your sacrifice in trawling through that dross on our behalf. Although I may never forgive you bringing it to my attention. I now understand the expression "It makes my brain hurt."

Comment: @Fortiter, it was Luke's fault -- he suggested it.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I did? Where?

Comment: @Luke, sorry -- my memory was playing tricks. It's lkessler who's to blame.

Comment: What a delightful game of 'pass the buck'. :)

Answer (score 2):

For those who need a graphic visualization (i.e., me):

> Category                                      | Yahoo! Answers | Genealogy SE
>
> Application of technology             |         10%            |         12%
>
> Research Process                       |         23%            |         28%
>
> Locating Records                        |         10%            |         30%
>
> Interpreting Records                    |          2%            |         13%
>
> Researching specific ancestors   |          8%            |         14%
>
> Specialist Topics                         |         38%            |         3%

**NOTE** Sum of given Yahoo data is not 100%

[image]

Comment: Numbers fixed in OP.

Answer (score 1):

If we exclude the 32 Yahoo questions concerning surnames and ethnicity (on the grounds that they would not have made it into the SE sample) then the differences are not nearly so marked.

[image]

Dare I suggest that only in "Interpreting records" is there a marked distinction.